# The type java.lang.Object cannot be resolved, it is inherently referenced from reuired .class files

Tags: java

I'm very new with this and I need help. I started project to practice using Jsoup and I think I messed up build paths for previous projects somehow. That project is working but projects before it don't work. It gives "java.lang.object cannot be resolved, inherently referenced from reuired .class files" and when I try run it says Error: Unable to initialize main class package1.ATHPOLD1 in module module module1
Caused by: module module1: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

pls help

Comment: Some code would be nice. Without it it's impossible for us to help you.

Comment: Anyway, `java.lang.object` doesn't exist. You probably meant `java.lang.Object` (with a capital O).

Comment: Yes sir, Object. On old project and the new ones I make it gives same error, on line 1 it automatically gives java.lang.Object error. Only on project where I did with Jsoup it works, that's also the only project where I have JRE System Library [CDC - 1.0/Foundation - 1.0] in class path. Is this somehow corelated?

Comment: Did you set the JAVA_HOME environment variable? Otherwise it won't find `rt.jar`

Comment: No, I just removed and then readded all libraries since google suggested thats how it should be fixed, it seems to be a bug in Eclipse, all worked smoothly :D ty for your interest sir though, much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

We get this error in Java when at Runtime, we are missing some dependency. Since you have not given any details about what your code is and what dependencies its using, I am not sure which one is missing.

Comment: Just fixed it, it appears it is Eclipse related bug, I need to remove and then readd all libraries. It actually was not a mistake on my end. :)